# Get text of selected item from dynamic list populated by adapter

Tags: java, android, getter-setter

I want to get the string value of TextView of a selected element of a list view which is generated through JSON data, adapter and getter & setter methods. I have tried multiple ways but not able to get the String value of the text.

I will pass this string value to further get data related to this selected item in the form of a JSON and start a new activity.

Below is my activity from which item is selected. The commented lines are all the things that I have tried.

```
public class Cat_Home extends AppCompatActivity {

String json_string;
JSONObject jsonObject;
JSONArray jsonArray;
ListView listView;
CategoryHomeAdapter categoryHomeAdapter;
String MOV_SUM_JSON,mov_sum_json;
String final_movie_name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cat__home);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_cat_home);
    categoryHomeAdapter = new CategoryHomeAdapter(this,R.layout.list_cat_home_element);
    listView.setAdapter(categoryHomeAdapter);
    json_string = getIntent().getExtras().getString("json_data");

    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
        jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
        int count=0;
        String name;

        while(count<jsonArray.length()){
            JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
            name = JO.getString("name");

            CategoryH categoryH = new CategoryH(name);
            categoryHomeAdapter.add(categoryH);
            count++;
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);

}

AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        //ListView listView1 = findViewById(R.id.list_cat_home);

        /*CategoryHolder1 categoryHolder1;
        categoryHolder1 = new CategoryHolder1();
        CategoryH categoryH1 = (CategoryH) categoryHomeAdapter.getItem(i);
        categoryHolder1.tx_name1.setText((categoryH1.getName()));*/


        //CategoryH categoryH = new CategoryH();
        //TextView textView;
        //textView.setText(categoryH.getName());
        //String selected_movie_name = categoryH1.getName();
        String selected_movie_name = String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));
        //categoryHolder1.categoryhold1();
        //String selected_movie_name = final_movie_name;
        //Log.d("tag_final_movie_name",final_movie_name);
        //String selected_movie_name = (String) categoryHomeAdapter.getItem(i);

        //String selected_movie_name = String.valueOf(listView.getItemAtPosition(i));
        //String selected_movie_name = listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
        Log.d("tag_selected_movie_name",selected_movie_name);
        BackgroundTaskGetMovSum backgroundTaskGetMovSum = new BackgroundTaskGetMovSum();
        backgroundTaskGetMovSum.execute(selected_movie_name);
    }
};
```

The log which I get of the selected movie name is below. As the string value is not coming for selected_movie_name, further when I am using it to get a JSON, I am getting an empty response.

```
D/tag_selected_movie_name: com.bmps.android.bollywoodmoviesplotsummary.CategoryH@79cae38
D/tag_mov_json: {"server_response":[]}
```

Below is my Adapter File

```
public class CategoryHomeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

List list = new ArrayList();

public CategoryHomeAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);

}

@Override
public void add(Object object) {
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View row;
    row =convertView;
    CategoryHolder categoryHolder;
    if (row==null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_cat_home_element,parent,false);
        categoryHolder = new CategoryHolder();
        categoryHolder.tx_name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.movie_title);
        row.setTag(categoryHolder);
    }
    else{
        categoryHolder = (CategoryHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    CategoryH categoryH = (CategoryH) this.getItem(position);
    categoryHolder.tx_name.setText(categoryH.getName());

    return row;
}

static class CategoryHolder{
    TextView tx_name;
}
}
```

CategoryH class

```
public class CategoryH {

private String name;

public CategoryH(String name){
    this.setName(name);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Comment: can you add a mock version of the JSON you are trying to parse , plus try to debug the JSON by Log.d("json" , json_string) ;

Comment: from the code snippet it looks like your list wouldn't even populate , you are setting adapter to the list view before parsing the JSON and added those items in the list without calling notifydatasetChanged()

Comment: @VutkaBilai The JSON debug is also present in the code. The tag is "tag_mov_json". The data which is used to populate the list from which I want to select the text is generated by a JSON (json_string) which is parsed by the activity before this and passed as an "Extra" with the Intent. 

The list is populating correctly in the emulator but after selecting an element I am not getting the required behavior.

Comment: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ use this website and give the json you are trying to parse . If I have the json I would love to solve  this problem from begging like writing the adapter and activity . from this code I can't get what is wrong going on

Comment: @VutkaBilai I want a json like this http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=b33a82c50802d04bf8278b97d0ed3889 to return from by BackgroundTaskGetMovSum Async task. When I am replacing the variable name in my php file with the exact name which should pass, the JSON is generated properly.

Comment: This blog post is doing exactly what you want , please follow this post 
[https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/][1]